# How to create small numbers in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am creating a small gravity simulator and I need it to "update" each particles position a small amount.

To do this I am trying to implement the increment of time increase in the equation

```
D = 1/2 A_g * T^2
```

to be a very small number such as .001 or even smaller.

In my attempt to do this I used 'float' because the rest of my array's were in that data type but that failed so I need help.

In my research of this topic I came across the variable type of 'BigDecimal' but I am confused on how to use this and I would not like to create a new variable for each one of my particles (Hopefully it can work with just another slot in my array's).

Comment: How did using `float` fail?

Comment: Yes, you can use objects such as `BigDecimal` in arrays in Java, if you declare the array as that type or a supertype thereof.

Comment: As @TedHopp said, how did `float` fail? 0.001 is not by far small enough to be "too small" to work with `float`s, so it is likely that you did something else wrong.

Comment: It says error "incompatible type possible lossy conversion from double to float"

Comment: Just use `double`....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct<sup>1</sup> answer is most likely to use `float`.  If you use it correctly, `float` is capable of representing numbers as small as `1.1755e-38` (normalized).

My guess is that you didn't write the `float` literal correctly.  The literal `0.001` is actually a `double`.  If you want a `float` literal you need to use an `f` or `F` suffix; i.e. `0.001f`.

(This guess is consistent with the error message ....)

---

<sup>1 - Changing to use `double` instead of `float` is also a good answer.  The difference is performance and space usage is unlikely to be significant, and the extra precision of `double` may be beneficial. On the other hand, the dynamics of n-body interactions are unstable.  Unless you get really deeply into the mathematics (numerical analysis) of solving the DE's numerically before writing your code, you are likely find that it is not floating point precision that limits the fidelity of your modelling ...</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much it works now lol sorry i am very inexperienced as a java programmer.

Comment: @Pi_Co if this answer solved your question, then please check it as Accepted Answer